# How to know which is the JSP webpage that is showing my servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jboss

I have a project that I can see the JSP's... However Jboss shows me the servlets so in the address bar all i can see is:

"appservleer?=AppDev"

This is an example not the actual address...but with that info only how can I know which JSP is being displayed at that moment by JBoss.

or am I understanding this Jboss, servlet, JSP incorrectly?

Some guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot know which `jsp` is being displayed unless the developer decided to give hints about it.

A [`jsp`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) is just a view technology that the servlet uses to render a response. That is, typically, the `jsp` will be parsed and html will be generated. However, the developer of the servlet may decide to write to the response himself. So nothing can really tell you if what you got came from a `jsp` or from another source, even if you had a url like `www.mydomain.com/page.jsp`. Nothing guarantees the response you are seeing in your browser was generated from a `jsp`.

Comment: exactly my point... I don't know exactly what is generating that particular webpage. however I do have access to the Code so I can access the web.xml, which I did and I found the name being displayed on the address bar but I have no idea what to do next as in to find the JSP being displayed.

Comment: @StevenHernandez You can take a loop at which `Servlet` is mapped to which url with the `url-mapping` elements. If you then have access to the servlet code, you can go see their implementation and check which `jsp` they might be forwarding to through a `RequestDispatcher`. There will be some relative path that points to it.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense so @pravat had some logic into his answer. But all these tacking process is done from web.xml by tracking the name of the servlet being shown in the addressbar?

Comment: @StevenHernandez Yes, Tomcat (or other servlet container) will use the `web.xml` file to pick a servlet that will handle your request by generating a response that **may or may not** come from a jsp. You really have to look at the servlet class source code to know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will definately look into this.

Comment: @StevenHernandez You're welcome. We have a great wiki you can take a look at on servlets. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know for sure which JSP is used for rendering is to look at the source code of the servlet that is mapped under (in your example) `"appservleer"`.

Look in `web.xml` which servlet is mapped with this path, and open the source code of this servlet. Then figure out the execution path, starting with the `doGet(...)` or the `doPost(...)` method, and see to which JSP it is forwarded in the end...

Good luck.

Comment: yes i found the web.xml and the name of the servlet, but this is the exact name to be found in my source code? so it would be appservleer.java?

Comment: The servlet should be defined as a <servlet> element containing a <servlet-name> and a <servlet-class> elements. The content of the <servlet-class> element is the exact class you are looking for. E.g. "com.mycompany.AppServleer". Then look in the source directory of your web project and open the corresponding java file, e.g. "src/com/mycompany/AppServleer.java"

Answer (score 1):

You should always start with the web.xml file which will eventually lead you to the actual jsp file that is displayed. Start with the servlet mapping and check which servlet is invoked for the url. Then dig into the servlet to find out which jsp it is redirected to. If you are using any application framework then look for the implementation to findout the mapping. For e.g. in spring the spring configuration files or the controller classes tells you where the calls are redirected to.

Comment: perhaps you are right, I would need to trace the actual JSP however @Sotorios  is saying something about not being able to know if its actually generated by JSP... so what else could be?

Comment: I agree. The response can also be generated by a servlet itself which is not a good practice but nevertheless, you can't stop it. Moreover, whether it is generated by jsp or servlet, you can always trace to the root if you start from web.xml.

Comment: exactly because that means that if the servlet itself is displaying the webpage, by arriving to the servlet I would be doing backtracking.

Comment: but if thats not the case, by looking at the requestdispatcher I would know which JSP is being used by the servlet.